# Fresh install of Haskell platform not working on MacOS High Sierra

Tags: macos, haskell, haskell-platform

I downloaded and installed Platform 8.4.3 as a pkg from the https://www.haskell.org/platform/. This is what I get when I try to run ghci immediately afterwards.

`$ ghci
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/gcc/7/libgcc_s.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/8.4.3-x86_64/usr/lib/ghc-8.4.3/bin/ghc
  Reason: image not found`

What did I miss?

Comment: You should probably file a bug against Haskell Platform as it seemingly requires gcc7 to be installed in `/usr/local` without mentioning it in the documentation. You may also try `stack` instead of Haskell Platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the related platform ticket, the problem was solved: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-platform/issues/310

It turns out that `ghc` builds from ghchq (at least through 8.4.3) don't link against the correct location for `libgcc_s.1.dylib`, but with the standard `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`, then libgcc is nonetheless discovered in `/usr/lib`. However, with a custom value for `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` then the library may not be found. So the solution is to not set a custom value, or to ensure that the custom value includes `/usr/lib`.

Comment: for the record, this is because ghc on os x is built using a brew installed gcc rather than the system gcc (which is really clang), due to clang compiling the GC code into something much less efficient: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7602 -- it still might be possible to do after-the-fact fixup of the paths, but this at least explains how the situation arises.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had a DYLD_FALLBACK_PATH set. The compiler looks for /usr/local even though the library is in /usr. Ticket has been submitted upstream.